# Merge 2 tables and fetch data one by one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like

[image]

Now, I want to display products on a page having 20 as a limit, the problem is firstly I want to display all those products on offer table arranged by offer_id desc and then display products on products table except those on offers table with in that 20 limit.

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), followed by a sort in descending order of `offer_id` (MySQL will place `NULL` values, such as one gets from the outer join where there is no matching record, last in such an ordering):

```
SELECT   Products.*
FROM     Products LEFT JOIN Offers USING (prod_id)
ORDER BY Offers.offer_id DESC
LIMIT    20
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86abf/1/0).

Comment: How will this exclude the `prod_id`s in offer table from product table?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: My understanding of the question was that products on offer should be shown first, followed by all other products up to a maximum of 20 in total.  Reading again, I'm still of that view.  What did you think the OP was after?

Comment: She wanted to display offers first and exclude the ids ( `prod_id` column of offer table) and print the products table with remaining ids... Well,this is what i understood..

Comment: Bhuvan is right.. & @eggyal this fiddle will work for me, let me try.. thanks